# Best way to organize Django fieldsets

Tags: python, django, django-admin

So I am in the process of creating a django admin view with customizable fieldsets based on the user's permission level. What is the best way to organize the fieldsets to reduce code repetition?

Currently, for 2 different fieldsets I have it set up like this:

```
standard_fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        (_('Permissions'), {
         'fields': ('is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'groups', 'permissions')}),
        (_('Dates'), {'fields': ('last_login',)}),
    )
perm1_fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        (_('Dates'), {'fields': ('last_login',)}),
    )
```

The goal of organizing the fieldsets will be to choose them as seen here:

```
def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        if # user has permission 1:
            self.fieldsets = self.perm1_fieldsets
        else:
            self.fieldsets = self.standard_fieldsets

        if not obj:
            return self.add_fieldsets
        return super().get_fieldsets(request, obj)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If fields inside a fieldset are always the same and in the same order, you can do something like this:

```
class SomeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = {
        'base': (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        'permissions': (
            _('Permissions'), {
                'fields': ('is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'groups', 'permissions'),
            }),
        'dates': (_('Dates'), {'fields': ('last_login',)}),
    }
    add_fieldsets = ('base', 'permissions')
    standard_fieldsets = add_fieldsets + ('dates',)
    perm1_fieldsets = ('base', 'dates')

    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        if not obj:
            fieldsets = self.add_fieldsets
        elif user_has_permission(1):
            fieldsets = self.perm1_fieldsets
        else:
            fieldsets = self.standard_fieldsets
        return [self.fieldsets[x] for x in fieldsets]
```